# Can this diagram represent an Iteration/for each in a Collection? Sequence Diagram or Activity Diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

i've this method **findNegozio(insertID)** used to find the element with **insertID** in a Collection.
So, findNegozio(insertID) is an operation that is often referred to in my sequence diagrams so I thought I would illustrate it as a sequence diagram.
The idea is to represent an iteration on a collection and take only the element that matches with the entered ID.

Could this be a good way to represent my idea?
is it useful to represent a frequent step of some sequence diagrams?

EDIT: Maybe with only one step is better OPT instead of ALT.

[image]

[image: mine code]

Comment: I do not understand the middle lineline

Comment: Use a flowchart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart

Comment: @OlegDmitrochenko do you mean activity ? the scope is UML

Comment: @bruno im going to find it on an ArrayList, if it check with ID it retuns. isnt like this?

Comment: @bruno Yes, it is)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram

Comment: @OlegDmitrochenko is it a good practice? I want represent it

Comment: @MrBuffalo who check the id ? how much level of collection do you have, 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @bruno when during the sequence diagram someone needs to get that Negozio by ID.

Comment: @MrBuffalo Yes. The sequence diagram is used in another case. It shows a sequence of actions between entities (objects, classes, modules, functions, actors, etc).

Comment: @OlegDmitrochenko warning a sequence diagram does **not** show actions . A sequence diagram shows an interaction (or a sub part of it). An activity diagram shows an activity (or a part of it), and actions are part of its scope. Interaction and activity are 2 different things, an activity is a behavior so can represent the body of an operation (as a state machine)

Comment: @OlegDmitrochenko okay, now im going to try with Activity Diagram

Comment: @bruno do u think i need an Activity Diagram to explain this?

Comment: @MrBuffalo the middle lifeline is still obscure, how the id of the elements is got ? It is your choice between interraction and activity

Comment: @bruno here i dont know how represent it.. in the code with iterator i can get the next element and take his ID, then check if the ID matches

Comment: @MrBuffalo may be add the code in your question ? that will allow to check your seq diagram corresponds or not

Comment: @bruno the part of getNegozio () on Negozio is probably useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First three remarks :

- For me your code is invalid because a *return* is missing after the loop => I suppose a variable *result* is added and initialized to *null*, set to the found item if exist, and finally used for a final *return*.
- Are you sure *findNegocio* is not *static* ?
- Why *findNegocio* is defined on *Negocio* and not on *GestoreNegocio* ?

A sequence diagram shows an interaction (partially or not) and focuses on message interchange between lifelines.

From the definition of your operation it is needed to decide whose messages are enough interesting to be shown in your sequence diagram. I don't think the details concerning the list and iterator have to be shown, they are very classical, the goal is not to explain how to work with Java builtin classes.

To break the loop you have the fragment *break*, so your sequence diagram can be (I added a caller because my tool does not manage lost/found messages) :

[image]

But perhaps the main information shown is the use of *GestoreNegocio* and the loop by itself is not really interesting ?

Comment: @MrBuffalo but I did not answer your question ? is your problem still open ?

Comment: `for each item in the list` is a strange name for a boolean flag. Also it is unclear who would update it. Why not use `loop(list.count)` instead? And `result:=item` is not a valid notation on a message. The assignement to variable `result` would be shown with a simple `=`. And `item` is a strange name for an operation that returns  the current item of an iterator. I suggest to use `getCurrentItem()`. Or just, as @bruno suggested, omit the loop completely. But if you show it, navigating to the next item should be shown as well with a `next()`-message.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer even I mainly agree with you I got these notations from training. The goal was to have something readable. Concerning "item" I just reuse "item" from "for each ...", the fact an iterator is used is completely hidden (forget) in the diagram